# Фрагментация в страничной организации операционной системы

Tags: c++, память, ос

Как может возникнуть фрагментация в операционной системе со страничной сегментацией? Или под этим понимают фрагментацию в реализации `malloc` и `new`?

Comment: Возможна *внутренняя фрагментация*, внтури страниц. Например, если размер страниц — 4KB, а размер загружаемой программы — 9KB, то программа в памяти займет 3 страницы, причем 3/4KB последней страницы не будут использоваться. Такие «дыры» и называют внутренней фрагментацией.

Comment: Вы ведь уже [задавали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058933/%d0%a4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8) этот вопрос.

Comment: @eanmos никто не ответил, и я решил переспросить с некоторым уточнением.

Comment: не стоит так делать. Если вы считаете, что вопросу уделено недостаточно внимания, то можете начать конкурс (предложить награду за ответ на вопрос) или просто отредактировать его, чтобы поднять в списке активных вопросов.

Comment: Вопрос совершенно не понятен. Фрагментация - явление логического уровня, уровня внутренней организации динамической памяти. Менеджмент свободных блоков в частности. Она никак не связана со страничной организацией памяти вообще. Реализацию динамической памяти можно немножко оптимизировать с оглядкой на страничную организацию, но не более того. К проблеме фрагментации страничная организация на относится вообще никаким боком. О чем речь вообще?

Comment: @AnT любая память в современных ос разбита на страницы, мне не понятно, как при таком устройстве может возникнуть фрагментация, поскольку я постоянно встречаю туторилы по типу: "Как сделать нефрагментированный аллокатор".

Comment: А я вам говорю, что страничная организация вообще никак не влияет на возникновение или не возникновение фрагментации. Я вообще не вижу тут никакой связи. Ваш вопрос говорит о том, что под "фрагментацией" вы понимаете что-то совсем другое. Пока вы не объясните, о какой такой "фрагментации" вы ведёте речь, вопрос не ясен.

Comment: @AnT ну у нас все адресное пространство разбито на страницы, и физическое и виртуальное, получается, что при переводе из виртуальной страницы в физическую, каждая виртуальная будет соответствовать физической, и никаких "дырок" не будет(что я и подразумеваю под фрагментацией)

Comment: @AnT мне кажется, я понимаю, фрагментацию немного на другом уровне, она может возникать в хипе программы, так как выделение происходит непрерывным куском, но не может возникать на физическом уровне, так как страницы кратны, я прав?