# Фрагментация в сегментной и страничной организации памяти

Tags: память, ос

Правильно ли я понимаю, что фрагментация в страничной модели возможна только на уровне виртуальной памяти, в отличии от сегментной? Но чем это лучше фрагментации на уровне реальной памяти, в любом случае придется делать дефрагментацию?

Comment: В страничной адресации у нас остается только *внутренняя фрагментация*, когда внутри самой страницы остается неиспользуемое место. При сегментной адресации существует и *внешняя фрагментация*: в памяти может появляться множество «дыр» —  свободных участков памяти небольшого размера между сегментами. В конце концов может сложится ситуация, когда **суммарный объем** сводной памяти (суммарный размер всех таких «дыр») достаточен для запуска процесса, но процесс запустить невозможно, из-за того, что у нас нет **непрерывной** области памяти достаточного размера.

Comment: @eanmos А по какой причине у нас не может быть внешней фрагментации? Допустим есть у нас хип(2гб), я выделяю 1ГБ страниц, далее 500МБ, потом снова 1ГБ и снова 500МБ, освобождаю оба фрагмента по 500, далее хочу выделить еще 1ГБ страниц, но из-за того, что они не последовательны не могу.

Comment: дело в том, что все страницы одинакового размера (обычно, 4KB).

Comment: @eanmos тогда вопрос в другом, зачем люди пишут алллкаторы с меньшей фрагментацией, если она невозможна(тот же линейный аллокатор)

Comment: Фрагментация *возможна*, но на другом уровне — на уровне аллокатора. ОС выделяет память для процесса *целыми страницами*. Аллокатор управляет списком занятых и свободных участков памяти *произвольного размера* и возвращает вам указатель на *уже выделенную* операционной системой память. Т. е. сам аллокатор ничего не выделяет, он может лишь попросить ОС изменить размер кучи в большую или меньшую сторону. На нашем с вами уровне абстракции вообще не существует страниц или сегментов, есть только непрерывное линейное адресное пространство.

Comment: @eanmos огромное спасибо, буду очень благодарен, если вы составите ответ.

Comment: Если никто более компетентный в этом вопросе не ответит, тогда составлю. Я сам несколько плаваю в этой теме, а всегда хочется иметь хороший, подробный ответ на хороший вопрос :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В страничной адресации у нас остается только *внутренняя фрагментация*, когда внутри самой страницы остается неиспользуемое место. При сегментной адресации существует и *внешняя фрагментация*: в памяти может появляться множество «дыр» — свободных участков памяти небольшого размера между сегментами. В конце концов может сложится ситуация, когда **суммарный объем** сводной памяти (суммарный размер всех таких «дыр») достаточен для запуска процесса, но процесс запустить невозможно, из-за того, что у нас нет **непрерывной** области памяти достаточного размера. В то же время, размер всех страниц одинаковый, поэтому в режиме страничной адресации *внешней фрагментации* быть не может.

Фрагментация возможна и на другом уровне — на уровне аллокатора. ОС выделяет память для процесса целыми страницами. Аллокатор управляет списком занятых и свободных участков памяти **произвольного размера** и возвращает вам указатель на *уже выделенную* операционной системой память. Т. е. сам аллокатор ничего не выделяет, он может лишь попросить ОС изменить размер кучи в большую или меньшую сторону.

На нашем с вами уровне абстракции вообще не существует страниц или сегментов, есть только непрерывное линейное адресное пространство.

---

*@avp в чате [уточнил](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52937106#52937106) некоторые моменты касательно фрагментации.*